# Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 wont boot after rooting

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, boot, rom

I try to Root my Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 with KingoRoot using pc.
after that it restarted, but now it won't boot.
when i try the button combination, `home+power+vol`, tab goes into downloading, odin, mode.
where can i find the Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 `(model: SM-T211)` flash firmware?

so that i can download and flash with this downloaded firmware ?

Answer (score 1):

You may find **stock firmware** for your model on **SamMobile** from this [link](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/SM-T211/).

This site is also a good source for firmware for most Samsung Mobiles. Just search for your model [here](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/). Do take note however that you have to *register for a free account* before you can start downloading. Optionally, upgrade to a premium account for faster download speed.